# Dieudonné theory over non-perfect base fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dieudonne

Is there a Dieudonné theory for $p$-divisible groups (or for finite flat group schemes of $p$-power order) over *non-perfect* base-fields?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Zink's theory of displays for p-divisible groups (https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~zink/Texel.pdf) handles general residue fields

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Johan de Jong sent me an e-mail with a reference to Jong, A.J. de. "Finite locally free group schemes in characteristic $p$ and Dieudonné modules" Inventiones mathematicae 114.1 (1993): 89-138. https://eudml.org/doc/144143.